# Spring mvc doesn't work post method in form

Tags: java, spring

When I started write application, form submited and *createAnnotation* method worked. Now it doesn't work. Why?
By the way GET method executes in controller, and POST doesn't.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/annotation")
public class AnnotationController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createAnnotation(@ModelAttribute Annotation annotation, BindingResult result){
        annotationService.create(annotation);
        return "redirect:/annotation/annotations.htm";
    }

}
```

```xml
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/annotation/new" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text">Annotation name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Annotation name" name="name"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="date">Date:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Date" name="date"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="comment">Description:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="description"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="profil.id" value="1"/>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: As a result in URL this address http://localhost:8012/test/annotation/new and empy page in browser

Comment: Can you check what is the logged message. Also try with removing the BindingResult from the argument.

Comment: Try changing "${pageContext.re......" to "new"

Comment: Can you provide command name in your jsp file under the form tag and same as a value of @ModelAttribute tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but when i've added this code in form tag, all fixed

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                                               value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

wTf???

Comment: Today i have this problem. I can explain to you what it is if true